# How to make multiple apps share a remote service in Android?

Tags: android, process, android-service

I have to write an Android SDK for my company's product API which will be used by customers' applications. The SDK will contain a background service running in a sparate process (By setting `android:process="com.my.sdk.process"` for the service in AndroidManifest.xml).

If there are multiple applications using my SDK, in order to save resources, how can I ensure that only one instance of the service process exists, not each application owns one instance?

Comment: For this u need to use aidl service mechanism..
Search on developer.android.com there is a proper example for how to use aidl ..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to have the service in a separate APK, which comes at a cost of having the user's go though an installation process of an APP.

But, if I understand correctly, you want to avoid this and have an instance of the same service in all your client apps and one of them is elected at any given point of time and all clients will then, communicate to this chosen Service using AIDL.

I have not tried it but we can try the following
1) Host the service in separate processes but have them share the same 
      
                
            
        
2) From your SDK that exists in all clients, bind the service using the intent
      Intent intent = new Intent("this.should.be.same.for.everybody");

Hopefully, All your service code in each of your Apps should recieve the callback. You can them implement the election/selection logic based on
1) The latest version
2) The first available
3) The capabilities
.. and so on.

You also have to be take the overhead of the following cases
1) What if the app that is hosting the running service un installs
2) What if there is an update 
     (a) Update the current running service
     (b) Update the service which was not running but after update, becomes a candidate for selection.

Let me know if it works.